# Can Windows XP use a Sun Solaris 10 server as a time server? How do I set it up?

Tags: windows-xp, solaris-10, time-server

I have several Windows XP machines on the same network as a Sun Solaris 10 server. I would like the XP machines to synchronise their clocks with the time on the Sun server. I have no internet connection on this network I was wondering how I should go about setting this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the Sun box run an NTP server.

On each WinXP system open the date/time control panel, switch to the Internet Time tab, and enter the name of the Sun box.

Unless the XP systems are part of an Active Directory domain, in which case they will (and must) synchronise time from one of the domain servers. The root domain server should be set to get its time from your root NTP service.

Comment: Usually inside a domain workstations synchronize their time with the server having the PDC emulator role. I think that was what you were saying but i just wanted to add this extra detail

Comment: thanks i suspected this was so. now how do i get ntp up on the sun box? i haven't been in linux since 2002 and even then it was other distros.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2006-February/007139.html and http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5059